# SQL Query to display a list of employees with the name of the department and the name of the head

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

to bring to the column the chiefs of their subordinates who are tied to one department. How can this be done? I tried different joins, but I couldn’t get the column of the remaining employees to their bosses. I'm new to SQL sorry, please.
I am getting the result only for the chief to name on the department but I can't add a column with employees.

```
SELECT 
    employee.name,
    employee.chief_id,
    department.name,
    department_id
FROM
    employee
        INNER JOIN
    department ON department.id = employee.chief_id
```

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function as follows:

```
SELECT 
    head.name as head ,
    department.name as department,
    GROUP_CONCAT(employee.name) as employess
FROM
    employee  

 INNER JOIN
    employee as head ON employee.chief_id = head.id

INNER JOIN
    department ON department.id = employee.department_id 

group by head.name,department.name
```

[image]

Comment: Also, please note that the join condition `department ON department.id = employee.chief_id` you used does not seem to be correct! @Georgy Fidarov